# How can i implement logout feature in NodeJs with keycloak

Tags: node.js, express, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I'm trying to implement a logout functionality with `keycloaks` which is running as a docker container.

When tried with postman I'm getting a 204 response, even after that I am able to access the web pages without having to login again (Hence logout has not happened correctly).

I have supplied the bearer token, client id, client secret and refresh token.

Please see the screenshots below from Postman.

[image]

[image]

Similarly have tried to implement these changes on nodejs using axios.But however things are not working.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');
var data = qs.stringify({
    'client_id': 'VideoKYC',
    'client_secret': 'my-clinet-secret',
    'refresh_token': 'refresh token from cookies'
});

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://3.109.1.86:8443/auth/realms/VideoKYC-Realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer my-token',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data: data
};

axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("data is");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Stack trace from where response is empty:

```
$ node logout.js 
(node:16732) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
data is
""
```

Ideally I think we should get some response, and the token should be invalidated and automatically be logged out.

Please help me implement these changes

Comment: I quickly checked www and found https://suedbroecker.net/2021/05/18/simply-logout-from-keycloak/ maybe worth studying this blog post

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me.

```js
const data = qs.stringify({
  client_id: 'your_kc_clientId',
  client_secret: 'your_kc_client_secret',
  refresh_token: 'your_referesh_token',
});
const config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: `${process.env.KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL}/realms/${process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/logout`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
  data: data,
};

axios(config)
  .then((response) => console.log('logout successfully'))
  .catch((err) => console.log('error!!!'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.